# TypeError AWS.KinesisVideo is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, npm-install, aws-sdk-js

I installed aws-sdk using the below command

```
npm install --save aws-sdk
```

and i get an error

> TypeError AWS.KinesisVideo is not a constructor

for the below code

```
var kinesisvideo = new AWS.KinesisVideo();
```

[AWS.IAM is not a constructor JavaScript SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47081457/aws-iam-is-not-a-constructor-javascript-sdk) post mentioned the error could be because the KinesisVideo module isn't present.

My question is how do i install all modules of aws-sdk via npm.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 main methods of downloading the full AWS SDK for browsers (load it in using a `<script>` tag) and Node.js backends.

1. **Download a custom SDK from the AWS website**

   You can choose which modules and services to download in the online SDK builder at **https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/**

   Click <kbd>Select All Services</kbd> and click <kbd>Build</kbd> to download everything.
2. **Use the CLI to build the SDK**

   Clone the official AWS SDK GitHub repository.

   ```
   <!-- language: lang-none -->

   git clone git://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js
   cd aws-sdk-js
   ```

   After you clone the repository, download the dependency modules for both the SDK and build tool via the following command:

   ```
   npm install
   ```

   You can now build a packaged version of the SDK from the command line interface.

   Execute the following command to build the SDK with all services and API versions included:

   ```
   node dist-tools/browser-builder.js all > aws-sdk-full.js
   ```

   If you want a minified bundle, set the `MINIFY` environment variable.

   ```
   MINIFY=1 node dist-tools/browser-builder.js > aws-sdk-full.js
   ```

   <sub>***You must have Git and npm installed for this to work.**</sub>

**Extra resources:**

- **https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/building-sdk-for-browsers.html**
- **https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/installing-jssdk.html**
- **https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js**
- **https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk**

Comment: That's the same approach i suggested ;)

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no way to install all modules together using npm.

But, You can use the SDK-builder tool from [aws-sdk-js](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) repo to create a minified bundle of ALL the AWS Services and include that bundle using `<script>` tag.

The command to generate a bundle of ALL the services:

`node dist-tools/browser-builder.js all > aws-sdk-full.js`

Check out this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/building-sdk-for-browsers.html#using-command-line-tools) for full-steps.

Hope this helps.